# Javascript Closure not providing expected result

Tags: javascript, closures

I am trying to understand closures.

```
var a = 1;

var g = function () {
  var a = a;
  return function() {
    console.log(a);
  }
}

g()();
```

As far as I know, the function invocation `g()()` should log the value of a, i.e. 1. But it is logging `undefined` on the console. I know my concept is weak somewhere, but am not able to figure out even after spending few hours. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript hoists `var` declaration in the entire function scope. The variable from the outer scope `var a = 1` is overwritten.
The example is equivalent to this:

```
var a = 1;

var g = function () {
  var a; // a is undefined
  a = a; // a = undefined
  return function() {
    console.log(a);
  }
}

g()();
```

Without initial value assignment, `a` is simply `undefined`. Later you assign the variable to itself `a = a`, which is a noop and `a` remains `undefined`.

For more information about variables hoisting, [check this article](https://rainsoft.io/javascript-hoisting-in-details/).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the line

```
var a = a;
```

This is both declaring a locally scoped variable and assigning it to itself - it's not interacting with the global `a`.  You need to use a differently named local variable:

```js
var a = 1;

var g = function() {
  var b = a;
  return function() {
    console.log(b);
  }
}

g()();
```